# Powerchute Windows10 and reducing power consumption while on UPS battery

Tags: battery, power, desktop-computer, ups

I have a computation app that can sense running on batteries, but does not trigger when PowerChute 3.1.0 is running on battery power (APC UPS1500 Pro).  That app knows the power is limited, but Win10 doesn't know, and so all the other apps and display run as if power is endless.

It seems that Windows Power Management is disabled (see other post like this one) by PowerChute app, which means Windows has lost the authority to do the battery status management.
[How to get UPS notifications in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1670903/how-to-get-ups-notifications-in-windows-10)

Has anyone re-enabled WPM with PowerChute installed?  Windows might not be able to know when the battery will die, since it probably can't ask the UPS via probably proprietary USB cable protocol?

I'll try to run some tests, but PowerChute is famously hard to uninstall without manually killing tasks, deleting registry keys and files.

Thanks!